# How to get xml tag value using attribute value in java

Tags: java, xml

How to get XML tag value using attribute value in java?

The format of XML is:

```
<str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">0</str> 
<str name="Total Rows Fetched">0</str>
```

Say for eg: I need to get tag value `0` using `Total Requests made to DataSource` value.

Comment: Check out an XPath tutorial.

Comment: It depends on which plugin you are using, normally there is a method `getAttribute("name")`

Answer (score 0):

Find the element using [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpath):

`//str[@name='Total Requests made to DataSource']`

Once you found the element(s), simply extract their text content.